# Can I migrate a question to another Stack site?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, migrated

If I am not getting enough responses and I believe admins in other stack site can answer this, is it possible to move to another site?

Ex: I have asked one Server logging(Linux) related question SF, but I am not getting enough responses. I used to get better responses in unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You** yourself can't.

But moderators can. You should be able to flag your own question for moderator attention:

> - **in need of moderator intervention**
>     A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be *specific* and *detailed*!

Please be aware that questions older than 30 days can't be migrated and we'll not always honour such requests either.

Comment: Thanks. I am flagging one of my question in SF.